# PHP two arrays compare

Tags: php

There are two arrays.

```
$array1 = ["apple", "banana", "grape", "watermelon", "taro", "coffee", "green tea", "tomato", "cabbage"];
$array2 = ["there is apple", "there is banana", "there is lemon", "there is melon", "there is cucumber"];
```

result I want is

```
$array2 = ["there is apple", "there is banana"];
```

Logic is check array2 contains any value from array1.

I can do it with a string and one array

```
$string = "apple";
$array = ["there is apple", "there is banana", "there is lemon", "there is melon", "there is cucumber"];
```

with two arrays quite hard.
Any advise please. Need to loop twice?

Comment: And what is the logic behind this?

Comment: @u_mulder check array2 contains any value from array.

Comment: Yes, you have to loop twice, because you have to test all the strings from `array2` for all the words of `array1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to loop once:

```
$array = ["apple", "banana", "grape", "watermelon"];
$array2 = ["there is apple", "there is banana", "there is lemon", "there is melon", "there is cucumber"];

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
   if(isset($array2[$k]) && strstr($array2[$k], $v)){
       $result[] = $array2[$k];
   }
}

print_r($result); // Array ( [0] => there is apple [1] => there is banana )
```

See [**Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63aeef2d0e1e0524e52652f2beb7aa25615f7d88)

Also take a look at [strstr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Comment: if array1 has values more than array2 occurs error right?

Comment: @wwwrrrxxx please check my answer again. I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `$array2` with keys, so you can check if the key exists in the array. When you check the key, it is exact. When you check for `lemon`, the `waterlemon` will not come up, else you have to check for that exception.

You could do something like this:

```php
$array1 = ["apple", "banana", "grape", "watermelon"];

$array2 = [
    'apple' => "there is apple", 
    'banana' => "there is banana", 
    'lemon' => "there is lemon",
    //...
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
   if (isset($array2[$value])) {
      $result[] = $array2[$value];
   }
}

print_r($result);
```